# how would you delete the repetitiveness of these 4 lines in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
    Most_Recent_Net_Income = float(json_r['financials'][0]['Net Income'])
    Net_income_1_year = float(json_r['financials'][1]['Net Income'])
    Net_income_2_year = float(json_r['financials'][2]['Net Income'])
    Net_income_3_year = json_r['financials'][3]['Net Income']
    Net_income_4_year = json_r['financials'][4]['Net Income']
```

I feel like this bit of code is very repetitive, and was wondering how I could simplify it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't use separate variables, use a list or a dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might help:

```
incomes = [i['Net Income'] for i in json_r['financials'][:5]]
Most_Recent_Net_Income, Net_income_1_year, Net_income_2_year,
    Net_income_3_year, Net_income_4_year = map( float, incomes)
```

if in you version of python `map()` returns `<map object>` or something, you might want to wrap that in `list()` to make it work better.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a single dictionary instead of multiple variables:

```
income_by_year = {}

for year in range(0, 5):
    income_by_year[year] = json_r['financials'][year]['Net Income']

print('Income in year 4:', income_by_year[4])
```

Or a dict comprehension:

```
income_by_year = {year: json_r['financials'][year]['Net Income'] 
                  for year in range(0, 4)}
```